# Is it possible to group by a few different date periods in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

There is a table `likes`:

```
like_user_id | like_post_id | like_date
----------------------------------------
1            | 2            | 1399274149
5            | 2            | 1399271149
....
1            | 3            | 1399270129
```

I need to make **one** `SELECT` query and count records for specific `like_post_id` by grouping according periods for 1 day, 7 days, 1 month, 1 year.

The result must be like:

```
period  | total
---------------
1_day   | 2
7_days  | 31
1_month | 87
1 year  | 141
```

Is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to aggregate this by `like_user_id` or `like_post_id`, or only return counts for all records as your sample output suggests?

Comment: What starting point is the time period to be decided from? Do they have to be rows or would a cross-tab query work for you? Is it for one user id or all?

Comment: I need to aggregate by `like_post_id`. Start period: from 1 year ago to current datetime.

Comment: `Do they have to be rows or would a cross-tab query work for you?`

It depends on performance.

Comment: in which date format the data is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a created a query for Oracle syntax please change it according to your db

```
select '1_Day' as period , count(*) as Total
from likes
where like_date>(sysdate-1)
union
select '7_days'  , count(*)
from likes
where like_date>(sysdate-7)
union
select '1_month'  , count(*)
from likes
where like_date>(sysdate-30)
union
select '1 year'  , count(*)
from likes
where like_date>(sysdate-365)
```

here idea is to get single sub query for single period and apply the filter in where to match the filter.

Answer (score 1):

This code shows how to build a cross-tab style query that you will likely need.  This aggregates by like_post_id and you may want to put restrictions on it.  Further, in terms of last month I don't know whether you mean month to date, last 30 days or last calendar month so I've left that to you.

```
SELECT
like_post_id,
-- cross-tab example, rinse and repeat as required
-- aside of date logic, the SUM(CASE logic is designed to be ANSI compliant but you could use IF instead of CASE
SUM(CASE WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(like_date)>=DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), interval 1 day) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 1_day,
...
FROM likes
-- to restrict the number of rows considered
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(like_date)>=DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), interval 1 year) 
GROUP BY like_post_id
```

Comment: Thank you! Your and Vikas Hardia's solutions works for me in two different situations!

Answer (score 1):

To be flexible, simply make a table `time_intervals` which holds from_length and to_length in seconds:

```
CREATE TABLE time_intervals 
(   id int(11) not null auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(255),
    from_seconds int,
    to_seconds int
);
```

The select is then quite straight:

```
select like_post_id, ti.name as interval, count(*) as cnt_likes
from time_intervals ti 
left /* or inner */ join likes on likes.like_post_id = 175 
     and likes.like_date between unix_timestamp(now()) -  ti.to_seconds and unix_timestamp(now()) + ti.from_seconds 
group by ti.id
```

With left join you get always all intervals (even when holes exist), with inner join only the intervals which exist.

So you change only table time_intervals and can get what you want. The "175" stands for the post you want, and of course you can change to `where ... in ()` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative using CROSS JOIN. First, the time difference is calculated using the TIMESTAMPDIFF function and the appropriate parameter (DAY/WEEK/MONTH/YEAR). Then, if the counts are equal to 1, then the value is added up. Finally, the CROSS JOIN is made with an inline view containing the names of the periods.

```
SELECT
  periods.period,
  CASE periods.period
    WHEN '1_day' THEN totals.1_day
    WHEN '7_days' THEN totals.7_days
    WHEN '1_month' THEN totals.1_month
    WHEN '1_year' THEN totals.1_year
  END total
FROM
(
SELECT
  SUM(CASE days WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 1_day,
  SUM(CASE weeks WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 7_days,
  SUM(CASE months WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 1_month,
  SUM(CASE years WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 1_year
FROM
(
SELECT
      TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, FROM_UNIXTIME(like_date), NOW()) years,
      TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, FROM_UNIXTIME(like_date), NOW()) months,
      TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK, FROM_UNIXTIME(like_date), NOW()) weeks,
      TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, FROM_UNIXTIME(like_date), NOW()) days
FROM likes
) counts
) totals
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT 
  '1_day' period
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
  '7_days'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
  '1_month'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
  '1_year'
) periods
```